# sed command not working properly

Tags: sql, bash, sed

I am executing

```
/bin/sed -i '/^$/d' $PRIMARY_K
    VALUE=`/bin/cat $PRIMARY_K`
    echo "$VALUE"
    PK=SYS
    NEW="$PK$VALUE"
echo "New Primary Key Constraint for $s- $NEW"  

 /bin/sed "s/$VALUE/$NEW/g" ../../../PartitioningUtility/sql/table7.sql > 
../../../PartitioningUtility/sql/exe.sql
```

last line `/bin/sed "s/$VALUE/$NEW/g"` is not replacing the value.

When I try with *HARDCODED* values, it's working.
E.g. I tried

```
/bin/sed "s/MAYUR/SAWANT/g"
```

Its working. 
Any suggestions.

Comment: so what are the values of `${VALUE}` and `${NEW}` before running `sed` (that is: as set by your script)?

Comment: SYS_C0010379      after that SYSSYS_C0010379

Comment: do you get any errors? which ones?? and are you sure you have `SYS_C0010379` in your sql-dump?

Comment: the output what i get is 

SYS_C0010379
New Primary Key Constraint for AGENTSTATEFACT- SSYS_C0010379

Comment: You probably have white space at the start or end of the line in $PRIMARY_K. Add a `cat -v "$PRIMARY_K"`, replace your `echo "$VALUE"` with `echo "\"$VALUE\""` and then post the output of running your script in your question rather than as snippets in comments.

Comment: what is the use of echo "\"$VALUE\""

Comment: "SYS_C0010379                                                                    "

Comment: Aha - notice the extra blank character between `9` and `"`?

Comment: I want to add numbering to the contain of Output File... What is the possible ways?

Now

ASD ASY WER WSD

After

1.ASD 2.ASY 3.WER 4.WSD

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to:

```
awk -v s="$s" '
NR==FNR {
    if (NF) {
        value = $1
        print value | "cat>&2"

        pk = "SYS"
        new = pk value

        printf "New Primary Key Constraint for %s- %s\n", s, new | "cat>&2"
    }
    next
}
{
    gsub(value,new)
    print
}
' "$PRIMARY_K" ../../../PartitioningUtility/sql/table7.sql > 
../../../PartitioningUtility/sql/exe.sql
```

to fix your current bug and pending performance, maintenance, reliability, etc. issues.

To put numbers before fields  on each row is simply:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s.%s",(i==1?"":OFS),i,$i; print "" }'
```

If that doesn't answer the question in your comments, ask a new question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I want to add numbering to the contain of Output File... What is the possible ways?

Now

ASD ASY WER WSD

After

1.ASD 2.ASY 3.WER 4.WSD

Comment: Update your question or, even better, post a new question but either way post sample input and expected output as it's not clear at all how what you're asking now is related to your original question.

Comment: stackoverflow blocked me